# How best to use docker in this situation

Tags: docker

I want to create a docker image of a web application running on redhat and that relies on an old DBMS (Informix). I want to run this application in my ubuntu machine. Here are some questions that I need your help with (I have no previous experience with docker):

1. How can I find the best redhat image to use and how? (when I searched in dockerhub with "redhat" as a keyword I got too much results and I do not know which one would be the right one).
2. Once I have an image of the os, I will need to install the informix DBMS. Is it possible to install proprietary software in a docker image?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It better to select official image if it exists. Official image has no prefix:

```
some_user/redhat - not official image
redhat - official image
```

If there is no official image you can select by stars count, or if you have some time better to read comments to image and dockerfile(best variant).

2) You can dockerize proprietary software. There is no needed to have source code in container - you can put any binary files to it. To know how to dockerize informix you can see github repos: https://github.com/0x1fff/docker-informix
https://github.com/nukedzn/docker-informix